# graphviz svg autoresize

Tags: php, svg, graphviz

I've got a graph made by graphviz **circo** (or **dot**, i guess in this issue there's no difference) in svg format and i'd like this image to be resized automaticly.
I know it can be done if i set

`<svg width="100%" height="100%"...`

but i can't realize how to make circo to do this.

The graph file for circo is generated in php like this:

```
$graph = "digraph structs {
node [shape=record, URL=\"http://localhost/gr.php?object=\N\"];
overlap = prism;
size=\"50,50\";`
```

I've tried `size=\"100%,100%\";` but circo translates it into `<svg width="3600pt" height="2946pt"`.
So, how can i make circo put `100%` in there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only thing worked for me is

```
$svg = file('circo.svg');
$svg[6] = preg_replace("/\d+pt/","100%",$svg[6]); //the line number is fixed
foreach($svg as $line)
{
    echo "$line";
}
```

maybe it will help someone =)